# How do I assign a timeout variable to the <v-alert> tag in Vuetify?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I would like to display an alert box which notifies the user about something. I would like it to disappear after 5 seconds even if the user didn't acknowledge it.

I already tried `timeout` and `:timeout` attributes but none of those seem to work and according to Vuetify docs they don't even exist in the  tag so I'm clueless.

**Template:**

```
<div>
      <v-alert
        :value="alert"
        v-model="alert"
        dismissible
        color="blue"
        border="left"
        elevation="2"
        colored-border
        icon="mdi-information"
      >Registration successful!</v-alert>
    </div>

    <div class="text-center">
      <v-dialog v-model="dialog" width="500">
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
          <v-btn color="red lighten-2" dark v-on="on">Click Me</v-btn>
        </template>

        <v-card>
          <v-card-title class="headline grey lighten-2" primary-title>Privacy Policy</v-card-title>

          <v-card-text>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</v-card-text>

          <v-divider></v-divider>

          <v-card-actions>
            <div class="flex-grow-1"></div>
            <v-btn color="primary" text v-if="!alert" @click="dialog = false, alert">I accept</v-btn>
          </v-card-actions>
        </v-card>
      </v-dialog>
</div>
```

**Script:**

```
import Vue from "vue";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      alert: false,
      dialog: false
    };
  },

  created() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.alert = false
    }, 5000)
  }
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In created hook add timeout range with 5s that update `alert` property with `false`:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data(){
    return{
       alert: true,
    }
  },
  created(){
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.alert=false
    },5000)
  }
})
```

in template bind `v-alert`'s `value` prop to `alert` data property :

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <div>
      <v-alert type="success" :value="alert">
        I'm a success alert.
      </v-alert>

    </div>
  </v-app>
```

check this [pen](https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/zYOLVGq?editors=1010)

Comment: please reshare the new code by adding a section called **EDIT** in your question

Comment: Had to create a new project and paste your code in it because the previous one had other problems. Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 3):

You could watch for changes to the alert property and set a timeout whenever the alert is set to true i.e. the alert is shown.

```
import Vue from "vue";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      alert: false,
      dialog: false
    };
  },
  watch: {
    alert(new_val){
      if(new_val){
        setTimeout(()=>{this.alert=false},3000)
      }
    }  
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use **Snackbar** instead that's what Vuetify called it

Then you just add this prop

```
:timeout="2000"
```

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/snackbars/#timeout

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
setInterval: 5000;
```

that should do the trick, its just like timeout!

but you still need to make a function for your timeout

maybe you should take a look on `w3schools.com`. and take a look with what you can do with alerts!

Comment: But where do I put this code exactly? I can't put it in the tag.

Comment: There are problems with recommending w3schools.com as a resource. Some of the solutions presented there include security problems like SQL injection.